# Access innerHTML of an anchor tag

Tags: jquery-selectors, selectors-api

I'm having trouble accessing some innerHTML that I need to use as a title for a menu bar:
See the attached image for details...

The title "AMRIS" is what I need to store to a javascript variable as a string.

I will later be using the following code to fill a Bootstrap menu with the title I grab:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">

var subTitle = document.getElementById("mobMenuTitle2");

//This is currently filling the Sub Menu with a title// 
subTitle.innerHTML = "Sub Test"; 

</script>';
```

**RIGHT-CLICK > OPEN IMAGE IN NEW TAB TO SEE FULL SIZE**

[image]

Comment: How are you currently trying to access that content?  How do you identify the element(s) you're looking for?

Comment: Currently trying this:

    var cinchItem = document.getElementById("accordion_menu_217");
    var currentOpen = document.querySelectorAll("cinchItem a");

Comment: then when I log the currentOpen, it gives me this: http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v257/cranigra/ScreenShot2014-05-06at34837PM_zpsec3d7b2f.png

Answer (score 1):

If you need the html of opend item, try like this

```
var openedList = document.getElementsByClassName('opened');
var menuLink = openedList[0].getElementsByClassName('menu-link');
var anchorText = menuLink[0].innerHTML;
```

Instead if you want to retrieve the html of list X (X is a numer 0 based)

```
var accordion = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion-menu');
var list = accordion[0].getElementsByTagName('li');
var menuLink = list[X].getElementsByClassName('menu-link');
var anchorText = menuLink[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: Getting a console error when I tried your first method: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of undefined

Comment: Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/bdB82/3/  maybe make a fiddle with your html

Comment: Got it using 2 lines of Jquery and then just .replace to cut it down to what I wanted:     var opn = $(".accordion-menu.opened.menu-link").context.title; var opnr = opn.replace("MagLab", ""); ... see below for my full solution...

Answer (score 0):

```
var opn = $(".accordion-menu.opened.menu-link").context.title;

var opnr = opn.replace("MagLab", "");

var subTitle = document.getElementById("mobMenuTitle2")

subTitle.innerHTML = opnr;
```

Comment: I don't have seen you needed jQuery. Just take a look,'context' will be no more supported by next jquery (was deprecated in jQuery 1.10). And IMO if you use jQuery use it to get all your elements (mobMenuTitle2)

Comment: ok, wow, so if I don't pull the context from the dom when jquery updates, I can pull something else and string replace it I'm thinking.. or you see better solution keypaul ??